# Wrong type being displayed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am just trying to figure out why this is happening.  I have a form with the following input

```
{!! Form::input('number', 'numTemplates', '1', ['id' => 'numTemplates', 'class' => 'form-control', 'min' => '1']) !!}
```

Now I presume number would be treated as an integer?  Within my Controller I am doing the following

```
$templates = $request->input('numTemplates');
dd(gettype($templates));
```

The output of this is "string".  So why would a number input be displayed as a string when using gettype?

Thanks

Comment: Anything in an input tag is a string. Doesn't matter what content it contains. a string made of numbers or a string made of alphanumeric values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a string because it's still a value of HTML form input. Just do type conversion, something like `intval($request->numTemplates)` or `(int)$request->numTemplates`

Comment: Thanks, will accept once it allows me to.  I knew I had to do type conversion, I just found it strange because the form input is a number so I would have presumed it would be treated as such